# Probability that a divisor of $10^{99}$ is a multiple of $10^{96}$

Tags: probability, elementary-number-theory

What is the probability that a divisor of $10^{99}$ is a multiple of $10^{96}$? How to solve this type of question. I know probability but  I'm weak in number theory.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

HINT: $10^n=2^n5^n$, so the divisors of $10^n$ are the numbers of the form $2^k5^m$, where $0\le k,m\le n$. Since there are $n+1$ choices for each of $k$ and $m$, $10^n$ has $(n+1)^2$ divisors. And $10^\ell\mid 2^k5^m$ if and only if $\ell\le\min\{k,m\}$.

Comment: $"10^n has {(N+1)}^2"$ divisors.can you explain this line?

Comment: @iostream007: The *Since* clause of the sentence **is** the explanation. There are $n+1$ possible choices for $k$, namely, the $n+1$ integers from $0$ through $n$, and similarly there are $n+1$ possible choices for $m$. The choices are independent of each other: you can combine any of the $n+1$ possible values of $k$ with any of the $n+1$ possible values of $m$. Thus, there are $(n+1)\cdot(n+1)=(n+1)^2$ possible combinations. Each of them yields a divisor of $10^n$, and by the fundamental theorem of arithmetic every divisor of $10^n$ must be of this form, so $10^n$ has $(n+1)^2$ divisors.

Answer (score 12):

As $10^{99}=2^{99}\cdot 5^{99},$

using divisor function [1](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/DivisorFunction.html),[2](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Divisor_function),  the number of divisors is $(1+99)(1+99)$

which are the product of  $$\{1, 2^1,\cdots,2^{98},2^{99}\}\text{ and }\{1, 5^1,\cdots,5^{98},5^{99}\}$$

To be multiple of $10^{96}$ we need to take $$\{ 2^{96},2^{97},2^{98},2^{99}\}\text{ and }\{ 5^{96},5^{97},5^{98},5^{99}\}$$ i.e., there are $4\cdot4=16$ of them

So, the required probability is $$\frac{4^2}{100^2}=\frac1{625}$$

Comment: The question says that the divisor of 10^99 should be a multiple of 10^96 which means that the divisor must be divisible by 10^96 ,so how can u say  that for the number to be a multiple of 10^96 we need to take numbers from 2^96 , I just took an example , like 2^4 =16 and 10^4 =10000, Now here 10^4 is a multiple of 2^4 ,not the other way round , since 2^4 divides 10^4 ,so then how can 10^96 divide 2^96 ?

Answer (score 5):

$10^{99}=2^{99} \times 5^{99}$

There are $100$ ways to choose the exponent for $2$ and $100$ ways to choose the exponent for $5$, so that $10^{99}$ has $10000$ distinct factors.

To be divisible  by $10^{96}$ both exponents must be at least $96$, which leaves the four cases $96, 97, 98, 99$ for each exponent. This amounts to $4 \times 4= 16$ cases.

Assuming the distribution is such that any factor is equally likely to be chosen, this gives $\frac {16}{10000}$.

Answer (score 0):

Since $10^{99} = (2\times5)^{99} = 2^{99} \times 5^{99}$,

Every factor of $10^{99}$ is of the form $2^p\times 5^q$

p and q can each be $0,1,2,...,99$ which is $100$ choices each.

So there are $100\times 100 = 10000$  factors of $10^{99}$

That's the denominator of the desired probability.

---

Next we calculate the numerator of the probability.

They are the positive integers of the form $2^p\times5^q$
which are multiples of $10^{96}$.

So p and q can can each be chosen as $96,97,98,99$

So there are $4\times 4$ = 16 factors of $10^{99}$ which are multiples of $10^{96}$.

Therefore the desired probability is $16/10000=1/625$.